# Is there a way to import local images in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know, I've imported local images before but it isn't working today.

I have this helper file which exports the images as an array

```js
const images = [
  require("../assets/1.jpeg"),
  require("../assets/2.jpeg"),
  require("../assets/3.jpeg"),
  require("../assets/4.jpeg"),
  require("../assets/5.jpeg"),
  require("../assets/6.jpeg"),
]

export default images;
```

Then I use them here to get a random image here

```js
//Random Image
const randomImg = () => {
  console.log(images);
  const UU = images[Math.floor(Math.random * images.length)];
  return UU;
}
const [hero, setHero] = useState(randomImg());
```

And then I get hat hero state in my jsx img tag

```html
<img
  className="headerImg"
  src={hero}
  alt="Hero Image"
/>
```

Why Isn't it working. I'm not using Next or gatsby or anything. I'm using React with webpack 2. Anyone know what is wrong?

Another interesting thing is that if I import a single image like this

```js
import hero from "../../assets/1.jpeg";
```

And Use It directly in the image

```html
<img
  className="headerImg"
  src={hero}
  alt=""
/>
```

Suddenly, it works. What is the Problem?

Thanks,
Lakshya

Comment: *"...in react?"* It's nothing to do with React, it has to do with your bundler.

Comment: I'm fairly new to React, apologies, but what is a bundler? I use vanilla react with webpack 2

Comment: **I think it's a typo.** I think if you look at `UU`, you'll find it's `undefined`, because the array doesn't have a `"NaN"` property. `Math.floor(Math.random * images.length)` is `NaN` because you didn't **call** `Math.random` (multiplying a function instance generally [always?] results in `NaN`). You want `()` after `Math.random`: `Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)`.

Comment: I tried using this ```const UU = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];```but it still isn't working

Comment: `require` will return a require object. Just use the `import` method you described in your question.